# Memoization not memorising when imported

Tags: python, django, import, global-variables, memoization

I try to use memoization to store a result. The function is called from a Django view, and the package in which the function's module is, is imported at the top of the view file.

*my_app/utils/get_peak.py*

```
MEMO = {}

def lookup_peak(carrier_code, environment):
    if carrier_code not in MEMO:
        response = urllib2.urlopen('someurl&carrier=' + carrier_code)
        html = response.read()
        start = html.find('PK')
        MEMO[carrier_code] = html[start:start+3].lower()

    return MEMO[carrier_code]
```

*my_app/views.py*

```
import my_app.utils as utils

class MapView(FormView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        peak = utils.get_peak.lookup_peak(carier_code, 'PRD')
        ...
```

If I start a debugger after peak assignment, I can see that `utils.get_peak.MEMO` contains the new value, but if I refresh the page (to make a new view request), `MEMO` is empty again and the if branch in the memoization module is evaluated again.

Anyone knows why this happens, and how to get this working properly?

It's as if the `get_peak` module is reevaluated every time and resetting `MEMO` to `{}`, but I don't see why that would happen. Shouldn't it get evaluated only on import? I'm only calling the function afterwards in the code, not the whole module.

**EDIT** I think the problem is that the module is imported every time, so `MEMO` gets reevaluated. I'm not sure why this happens as I expected the `urls.py` controller to only load the relevant view. What's a way around this then?

Comment: @TonyBlundell No, that is simply not true. Anything defined at module level will persist for the life of the server process, which can be many many requests.

Comment: @confused00 modules only get imported once per process, that's why memoization works at all. Are you sure that you are not triggering a reload of the server process in between requests somehow? Normally that should not happen, but if you are using the dev server it reloads on code changes, for example.